# Problem with installing Grub, after eOS installation.

Tags: dual-boot, grub, microsoft-windows

so i was trying to install elementary OS Juno on my laptop Lenovo ideapad Y700-15 isk and i had problems with Grub installation after whole process which made me unable to boot up eOS. I had same problem when i was trying to install Ubuntu. I got two drives, ssd with windows 10 on it and hdd where i made a partition for elementary OS only in ext4 format on which i tried to install eOS.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in similar situation. try to install juno/win 10 in same SSD, no matter how I try(different layout/format), all failed in grub installation.

but use 'full disk' installation is always OK.

Comment: Okay i'll try it :)